# Dependent reactive filters not working as intended (after using observeEvent & updateSelectInput)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

This is the test dataset. I have created two reactive filters from the columns category and sub.category from the dataset. In addition to reactivity, both these filter values are related where a record when selected from the category then its corresponding sub category records are displayed in sub.category filter. But the problem I am noticing is when all the filters values are cleared/empty, I am not able to click the sub.category filter and see all distinct values from it. I would appreciate if this is resolved.

[image]

```
category<-c('AA','AA','AA','AA','AA','BB','BB','BB','BB','BB')
sub.category<- c('A01','A01','A02','A02','A03','B01','B02','B02','B03','B03')
val1<-c(1,1,2,5,2,4,3,1,1,1)
val2<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
val3<-c(4,5,5,6,6,3,6,8,1,1)
val4<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

testdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(category,sub.category,val1,val2,val3,val4)


#testdata <- read.csv("testcsv.csv")

## Filters
cat_name <- unique(testdata$category)
cat_sub_name <- testdata %>% select(category, sub.category) %>% 
  distinct() %>% arrange(sub.category)


# Server function to determine the input and output parameters
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ### Combined ALS Metadata repository  
  df_testdata <- reactive({
    
    if (is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory))
    {
      testdata
    }
    
    else if (is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory))
    {
      
      testdata %>% filter(sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
      
    }
    else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & is.null(input$test_subcategory))
    {
      
      testdata %>% filter(category %in% input$test_category)
      
    }
    else if (!is.null(input$test_category) & !is.null(input$test_subcategory))
    {
      testdata %>% filter (category %in% input$test_category & sub.category %in% input$test_subcategory)
      
    }
    
    
  })
  
  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(df_testdata(), style = "bootstrap", filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE), options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, searching = TRUE)))
  
  
  ## Dependent reactive filter
  observeEvent(input$test_category, {
    
    
    subcatToShow = cat_sub_name %>% 
      filter(category %in% input$test_category) %>% pull(sub.category)
    
    #Update the actual input
    updateSelectInput(session, "test_subcategory", choices = subcatToShow, 
                      selected = subcatToShow[1])
    
  })
  
  
}

# UI section of the program to design the front-end of the web application 

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme('darkly'),
  
  titlePanel("Analysis Dataset", windowTitle="Category Dataset"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    mainPanel(
      width = 10,
      DT::dataTableOutput('tab1')
    ),
    
    sidebarPanel( width = 2,
            
                                   selectInput("test_category",
                                               choices = cat_name, 
                                               label = "Select the category name",
                                               multiple = TRUE),
                                   
                                   selectInput("test_subcategory",
                                               choices = c(), 
                                               label = "Select the sub category name",
                                               multiple = TRUE)
                                   
                  
            )
    
    
      
       )
  
  
  )

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
  ## Dependent reactive filter
  observeEvent(input$test_category, {
    
    if (is.null(input$test_category)) {
      subcatToShow = cat_sub_name$sub.category
      selected <- character(0)
    }else {
      subcatToShow = cat_sub_name %>% 
        filter(category %in% input$test_category) %>% 
        pull(sub.category)
      selected <- subcatToShow[1]
    }
    
    #Update the actual input
    updateSelectInput(session, "test_subcategory", choices = subcatToShow, 
                      selected = selected)
    
  },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

Comment: If this answered your query, please consider accepting the answer as it will help others.